# Can't add gms play services 9.0.1, google-services plugin wants 9.0.0

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have this in my top-level build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

And in my app-level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'
}
```

And I get this error when sync-ing gradle:

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the
>   google-services plugin […] or updating the version of
>   com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

Yet I'm already using 9.0.1, I don't get it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

That's because you should always put the "apply plugin" clause at the bottom for google-services, since it looks for the already-added dependencies. Do it like this in your app-level gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'
}
// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This is hidden in the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup#add_the_sdk), but applies even if you don't use Firebase.

Note : Update Google Repository also.

Comment: Same problem, mine was already set like this and made no difference. What did work for me was updating firebase-core to 9.0.1, appears both must be upgraded at the same time (writing this 9.0.2 of the play services has been released, updating both it and the firebase-core worked again)

Comment: Nice tip: after moving apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' to the bottom of your file, make sure you have apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' only once in your build.gradle file... :)

Answer (score 4):

Check the version of google services that you have in your root level build.gradle. This should be 3.0.0 or higher:

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.0.2'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I have in my question: "top-level build.gradle" means "root level build.gradle".

Comment: Have you tried upgrading Google Repository and Google Play Services via the SDK Manager? And you have no other dependencies that might conflict, like firebase or other google things?

Comment: I had upgraded to the latest available versions, and no confliciting dependencies. I solved the issue the way I posted in my answer :-)

Comment: Updating my Google Repository and Google Play Services solved the problem here - thanks @MrBigglesworth ! Had to change "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'" to "compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'"

Answer (score 1):

Update `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.2` and `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2` to same version(latest version) and sync the project.
Check if plugin is added on bottom like this.

```
dependencies {


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
..................

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```