# update google services from 9.0.0 to 10.0.1 Android studio 2.2

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, google-play-services

I get an error saying

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

I tried looking at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/ and com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0 seems to be the latest. This is my project gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And this is how my app gradle looks like

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sk.tipos.paradox02.citaj"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 27
        versionName '2.003'
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          //  signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }


    productFlavors {
    }

    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:9.8.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

If I change the play services to 9.0.0 everything compiles fine. What am I missing here?

Have you idea how resolve problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are having this issue because Firebase was built using Google Play Services , so you can't use a version of Google Play Services higher than the version of Firebase.

Can you try :

`apply plugin: 'com.android.application'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "sk.tipos.paradox02.citaj"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 27
        versionName '2.003'
    }


    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
          //  signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            multiDexEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt')
//            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }


    productFlavors {
    }

    lintOptions {

        checkReleaseBuilds false

    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.0'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Sorry for my english, hope it's help.

Comment: @user7575308 Please consider accepting the answer if it was hepful, so that it helps others as well.

Comment: nope .. :( 

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.0. ------------ in your code missing  com.google.android.gms:play-services: ....

Comment: No, nothing missing , no need to include 'com.google.android.gms:play-services'.

Have you try without com.google.android.gms:play-services' ? You can try to clean and rebuild the project as well.

Answer (score 1):

You are using different versions of dependencies.Update their version to match version of latest google services version.

e.g.

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appindexing:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:10.2.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:10.2.0'
```

Comment: move this line apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' at bottom of gradle file

Comment: no.. Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.
> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.2.0.

Comment: remove this line too -    compile 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' from gradle

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the solution given in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37565535/3108709 . I had the same issue as you had, this solved it for me.

> That's because you should always put the "apply plugin" clause at the bottom for google-services, since it looks for the already-added dependencies. Do it like this in your app-level gradle:
>
> `dependencies {
>       compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.0.1'
>   }
>   // ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
>   apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`
>
> This is hidden in the Firebase documentation, but applies even if you don't use Firebase.
>
> Note : Update Google Repository also.