# AndroidStudio Failed to Sync Gradle project, Failed to find target Google Inc

Tags: android, gradle, synchronization

How can I resolve the Gradle Sync problem?
I installed the missing SDK versions but the error shown again.

Take a look to the screenshots please...

[Screenshot 1](http://www.uzemanyagfogyasztas.hu//pics/AndroidStudioProblemGradleSync.png)
[Screenshot 2](http://www.uzemanyagfogyasztas.hu//pics/AndroidStudioProblem.png)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your compileSdkVersion must be a number, not a String

Example:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourpackage.yourapp"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 4
        versionName "1.3"
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to open up "build.gradle" script and change the classpath to latest gradle repository.... mine is 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha3'

Hope this helps everyone