# Android Studio Grade sync error - failed to find target

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, synchronization

I have the same issue as is described in this post: [AndroidStudio Failed to Sync Gradle project, Failed to find target Google Inc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549667/androidstudio-failed-to-sync-gradle-project-failed-to-find-target-google-inc)

My exact error in Gradle Sync is "Failed to find target Google Inc.: Google APIs:19 : C:\Users\Steve_Android\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk"

The code is here:[FtcRobotControllerActivity](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Byxg512qAqFgWkJEVldtLTB3MEU/view?usp=sharing).  I did not write this code myself, I am trying to use it with a robotics application.

I cannot comment yet so I need to ask another question here.  Is that answer sufficient and, if so, where does that script go?  I do not have that anywhere in the app code that I am working with.

Comment: No, the Answer Given there is not enough.. Please include the error message you got in your question.

Comment: I just updated the post to include the error message.

Comment: Can you please attach your gradle code too? I want to see what buildTool and compileSDKVersion you use..

Comment: The code is now posted in the original question.  Thanks.